# Java - Not getting html code from a URL

Tags: java, html, url, httpurlconnection

I want to get the html source code of `https://www2.cslb.ca.gov/OnlineServices/CheckLicenseII/LicenseDetail.aspx?LicNum=872423`
and for that I am using this method but I am not getting the html source code.

```
public static String getHTML(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn; // The actual connection to the web page
    BufferedReader rd; // Used to read results from the web page
    String line; // An individual line of the web page HTML
    String result = ""; // A long string containing all the HTML
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the line `rd.readLine()` is null even for the first time.

Comment: Can you provide us more context? What do you mean by "not getting the html source code"?

Comment: @JavierIEH The method is returning emtpy string

Comment: Have you tried `curl` (command line utils) to get the html? Some website check if the request is coming from a web browser.

Comment: @gigadot I think that server can that whether the request is coming from the browser or not by looking at the `User-Agent` http header. Is there any other way also by which it can check this?

Comment: `User-Agent` and `referer` are the common uses for server to check if the website is coming from web browser or the links are coming from the same host. `referer` is less reliable. Some people block them from sending out due to privacy concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server filters out Java's default `User-Agent`. This works:

```
public static String getHTML(URL url) {
    try {
        final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Foo?");
        final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        final String html = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        return html;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Looks like the user agents are black listed. By default my JDK sends:

```
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_26
```

Note that I'm using [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) class to simplify example, but the key things is:

```
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Foo?");
```